# Error fclose() and foreach() in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a bunch of fields, and I want the content from each field to be retrieved and posted to a text file, but each field's data be stored on a new line. So I've tweaked a snippet that I found, and it works great, does what I want. I checked the console, and it's giving an error. I'm really new to PHP, and I'm hoping someone can help.

Errors:

```
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
    Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given.
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST)){
        foreach($_POST["textdata"] as $text){
            if(!file_exists($_POST['filename'] . ".txt")){
                $file = tmpfile();
            }
            $file = fopen($_POST['filename'] . ".txt","a+");
            while(!feof($file)){
                $old = $old . fgets($file);
            }
            file_put_contents($_POST['filename'] . ".txt", trim($text).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$_POST['textdata']` is not an array, so for the foreach loop never executes. It jumps straight to the `fclose()` call. Since you never executed your loop, `$file` was never defined, so you're closing a null file handle.

If you want `textdata` to be an array, then it'd have to be defined with `[]` in the field name in your html:

```
<input type="text" name="textdata[]" />
                                 ^^---necessary.
```

In the bigger scheme of things, you should have your fclose inside the loop:

```
foreach(...) {
   $file = tmpfile();
   blah blah blah
   fclose($file);
}
```

That way you only close $file if it was actually opened in the first place.

Comment: textdata[] is the name of all the input text I want to retrieve data from. It works, it uploads the text file, each input text's data is on a new line. I just get those errors.

Comment: then you'd have to explode `textdata`. php won't turn a multi-line string into an array for you.

Comment: Placing fclose inside the foreach loop did fix the error, so how would I go about exploding textdata?